# How do I get the volume of the directory on the MapR filesystem?

Tags: mapr

I want to find out the volume of directory /mapr/clustername/dir1/dir2 in the MapR FS via the command line

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to look up the primary FID of the file (or the FID of the dir), note the container ID contained in the FID, then dump the info for the container, which will list the volume to which it belongs.

E.g. Step 1, list the FID:

```
[root@tssperf01 ~]# hadoop mfs -ls /path/to/file
Found 1 items
-rwxr-xr-x  Z U U   3 root root          0 2018-09-05 09:38  268435456 /path/to/file
           p 2049.404.269954  tssperf08.lab:5660 tssperf01.lab:5660 tssperf02.lab:5660
[root@tssperf01 ~]# hadoop mfs -lsd /path/to/dir
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x  Z U U   - root root          0 2018-09-05 09:40  268435456 /path/to/dir
           p 2049.408.269956  tssperf08.lab:5660 tssperf01.lab:5660 tssperf02.lab:5660
```

In both of the above cases, you should be looking for the line following the file/dir path, which starts indented then the letter 'p' for "primary" FID.  The container ID is the first number in that FID, in this case, 2049.

Then dump the info for the container and look for the VolumeName field, e.g.:

```
[root@tssperf01 ~]# maprcli dump containerinfo -ids 2049 -json
{
    "timestamp":1536161901817,
    "timeofday":"2018-09-05 09:38:21.817 GMT-0600",
    "status":"OK",
    "total":1,
    "data":[
        {
            "ContainerId":2049,
            ...
            "VolumeName":"mapr.cluster.root",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command to use:

```
maprcli volume info -path /dir1/dir2 -json
```

You get the volume info if this is the root dir of a volume. If the directory is a sub directory, you get an error message. Go as many directories as you need to to find your mount point